# Code rendering bug on closing XML literal

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown-rendering, code, xml

There's a small bug on rendering markdown [visible in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784133/how-can-i-convert-scala-xml-elem-to-something-compatible-with-the-javax-xml-apis/1787582#1787582) and copied here.The following seems to work just fine:

```
val schemaXml = <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <xsd:element name="foo"/>
                </xsd:schema>
val schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

But when the extra lines are added:

```
val schemaXml = <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <xsd:element name="foo"/>
                </xsd:schema>
val schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

// not possible, but what I want:
// val schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaXml)
```

The SchemaFactory.newInstance line and the closing XML tag) is all rendering as if it were a literal String

Comment: Google prettify, issues, http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list, etc

Comment: For some reason Google Prettify thinks it is a C/Perl related language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Google prettify, which is what we use for syntax highlighting, supports this:

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Not that I necessarily think that this is the case here but would you considering committing patches to prettify if it could be fixed?